# How do i make my UIImagePickerController auto rotate?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, subclass, autorotate

I tried to sub class the `UIImagePickerController` and return YES from `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` But this didn't work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html)

> Important: The UIImagePickerController
>   class supports portrait mode only.
>   This class is intended to be used
>   as-is and does not support
>   subclassing.

So I don't think your approach is going to work.

Comment: so how does the iphone camera roll work ? is there a camera roll controller ?

Comment: Check this answer to a [very similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1974858/uiimagepickercontroller-overlay-autorotate/1993979#1993979).